# Spring MVC Controller cannot process JSON produced by JSON.Stringify()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I keep getting the following exception when I try to send the following request to my Spring Boot MVC controller. The JSON payload contains '\' characters but this has worked in the past with Jersey. I wonder am I missing some common Spring Boot config.

```
  curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "phone": "+4489325678" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:8080/api/api/v1/auth/code'




 {
  "timestamp": 1495086719419,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "path": "/tappter/api/v1/auth/code"
}
```

My controller is configured like so.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@Api(value = "/auth", description = "Authentication", tags = "Authentication", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public class AuthResourceImpl implements IAuthResource {

    private final IAccessCodeService accessCodeService;
    private final IUserAccountService userAccountService;
    private final ITokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthResourceImpl(IAccessCodeService accessCodeService, IUserAccountService userAccountService,
                            ITokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        this.accessCodeService = accessCodeService;
        this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    @ApiOperation("Request Access Code")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Access Code Sent", response = AccessCodeResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid Number", response = Errors.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/code", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<AccessCodeResponse> requestAccessCode(@Valid @RequestBody AccessCodeRequest request) {
        AccessCode newAccessCode = accessCodeService.create(request.getPhone());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AccessCodeResponse(newAccessCode.getAccessCode()), CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: Can you try this request? `curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"phone":"+4489325678"}' 'http://localhost:8080/api/api/v1/auth/code'`

Comment: why do you want to send data with `-d` in a `GET` request?

Comment: The same error occurs when using Ajax requests e.g `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: You can not pass data whenever try for ajax GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like more of a curl problem. You're trying to send data in a `GET` request. Either don't provide the `-X GET` - curl will then default to `POST` if you're providing data using the `-d` flag, or explicitly use `-X POST` (for the sake of completeness, `-X PATCH` also supports data).

Comment: I get the same error if I use the Swagger UI.  It's not specific to CURL.